# MS Access 200X Image export with PHP?

Tags: php, ms-access, sqlite

i'm using mdbtools to get data from MS Access to sqlite... using PHP but now i want to get an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally answered my own question. All the details are posted here:

https://beeznest.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/leer-imagen-desde-un-campo-ole-object-de-access-con-php/

(spanish)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code that you have attempted?  Errors?  If I remember right, there should be ample information in PHP's documentation about retrieving information from a SQLite source (if I remember right).  Are you storing the image IN the Access database, or just a link to it?

If it's the former, I am not sure if there is a way to retrieve this information with PHP and have an image that you can view (considering Access stores images as Bitmaps) without a lot of conversion and figiting with data types.

If you are storing just a link to the image, you'd retrieve it like any other piece of data, inserting it where appropriate in the IMG tag.